# Return the string equivalent of a SELECT that only returns one value

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have a SELECT query that only returns one value (not one row, but just one "thing"). It looks like

```
SELECT IF( EXISTS( SELECT * FROM `Blah` WHERE <whatever> ), 1, 0);
```

I tried fiddling around with `mysqli_result::fetch_assoc`, `mysqli_result::fetch_object` and `mysqli_result::fetch_array`, and all of them are being really weird. Is there a `mysqli_result::fetch_string` for special cases like this that just outputs a string on which I can just call `intval`?

Comment: is one "thing" is a row in your table?? if yes, then why dont you write select thing FROM `Blah` WHERE <whatever>

Comment: you can use `mysql_num_rows()` in PHP, and based on `WHERE` it will be 0 or 1

Comment: @SandeepBhandari Not quite, I need to perform an operation on another table which is conditional on an entry existing in this table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
SELECT IF( EXISTS( SELECT * FROM `Blah` WHERE <whatever> ), 1, 0) AS exists;
```

And use any of the functions above to get row number 0's 'exists' column.

Answer (score 3):

Aswell as casraf's answer, another option might be to incorporate a count into this - you might want to find out just how many blah's match your criteria later. Might be easier to read back when you re-visit your code in a years time, too.

```sql
SELECT count(*) cnt FROM `Blah` WHERE <whatever>
```

You'd be able to do a boolean check on the "cnt" variable (i.e. a count of 0 would == false) but also use it to find out how many matches you've got.

Comment: Good tip, I would recommend to do this if OP thinks the scope might be larger in the future.